# ngx-virtual-scroll is not working after angular16 updation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular16

ngx-virtual-scroll  is not working after angular16 updation, showing one error in the terminal.

The error is

```
'VirtualScrollerModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.
This likely means that the library (ngx-virtual-scroller) which declares VirtualScrollerModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer 
version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
```

How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

check out this fork [@iharbeck/ngx-virtual-scroller](https://github.com/iharbeck/ngx-virtual-scroller)

Answer (score 0):

this packaged wasn't updated for a long time. looks like it's not maintained anymore.
You can fork the project and update/maintain it yourself or use some alternatives like ngx-infinite-scroll (for infinite scroll) or Angular CDK scrolling https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview